# How to use variables in Oracle PL/SQL Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I'm sorry upfront because this question seems to easy.
I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Costs_MK (VIEWNAME IN VARCHAR2 , WHERE_CLAUSE IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2

IS
   v_Costs VARCHAR2 (500);

BEGIN

  Select Listagg(Costs, ';' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Costs)
  into v_Costs
  from (select distinct (Costs) 
        from VIEWNAME
        where WHERE_CLAUSE);

  RETURN v_Costs;
END Costs_MK;
```

However I get the Error-Message:

> Error(13,30): PL/SQL: ORA-00920:  invalid relational operator

I even can't compile it. If I use the exact values for Viewname and Where_clause I get the desired result.

What am I doing wrong?

/edit: Line 13 is

```
from VIEWNAME
```

/edit #2:
Thanks guys. You helped me a lot. I didn't thought about dynamic sql in the first step, so thanks for the refresher ;).

Comment: `from VIEWNAME`  you can't use a variable here ... you need to use dynamic SQL .. and that immediately begs the larger question : "What are you trying to do?" .. because resorting to Dynamic SQL for something like this can often be a sign of a poor design .. ;) (not always .. but often)

Comment: `where WHERE_CLAUSE`  this also won't work like this without dynamic SQL ... (see above)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use the return value in my procedure. I get the Viewname in my procedure during runtime and I would like to call the function with the viewname and then get my return value. Otherwise I would have to write 5 functions only to get the values. Same Problem with "where WHERE_CLAUSE". Any suggestions for a solution? So dynamic SQL?

Comment: I'd probably use 5 functions .. 1 for each view ... but that's just me .. :)  Others might disagree.

Comment: How "dynamic" the where clause is ? Is it always the same for the view ?

Comment: Sadly not. The "where_clause" is always different depending on the view an I get it during runtime. The bad thing is, that I have 8 different columns and 5 views. So I need to use 8 functions for each column, so I can call them whenever I need them in my procedure. Kind of complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add `EXCEPTION BLOCK` along with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
I have created a `PROCEDURE` you can similary create `FUNCTION`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Costs_PK(VIEWNAME IN VARCHAR2 , WHERE_CLAUSE IN VARCHAR2 ) 
  AS
v_Costs VARCHAR2 (500);
sql_stmnt varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
sql_stmnt := 'Select Listagg(Cost, '';'' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Cost) from (select distinct (Cost) from ' || VIEWNAME || ' where ' || WHERE_CLAUSE || ' ) ';
--sql_stmnt := 'Select Listagg(Cost, '';'' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Cost) from (select distinct (Cost) from cost_tab where cost >=123 ) ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmnt INTO v_Costs ;
dbms_output.put_line ('query   works  -- ' || v_costs);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS  THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('input :' || VIEWNAME || ' and  ' || WHERE_CLAUSE );
dbms_output.put_line (sql_stmnt );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR MESSAGE : ' || sqlCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM );
END;

begin
Costs_PK('cost_tab','cost >= 123');
end;
```

`NOTE:` code has been Tested

**output:**

```
query   works  -- 123;456
```

[image: TESTED]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the areas in PL/SQL where the most straightforward static SQL solution requires code duplication as there is no way to parametrize the table name in a query. Personally I usually favor duplicate code of static SQL over the increased complexity of dynamic SQL as I like PL/SQL compiler to check my SQL compile time. YMMV.

You don't tell us what kind of `where` statements the different views are having. In the example below I assume there is 1:1 relation between the view and where parameter(s) so I can easily build static SQL.

```
create or replace view foo_v (foo_id, cost) as
select level, level*10 from dual connect by level < 10
;

create or replace view bar_v (bar_id, cost) as
select level, level*100 from dual connect by level < 10
;

create or replace function cost_mk(
  p_view in varchar2
 ,p_foo_id in number default null
 ,p_bar_id in number default null
) return varchar2 is
  v_cost varchar2(32767);
begin
  case lower(p_view)
    when 'foo_v' then
      select listagg(cost, ';' ) within group (order by cost)
        into v_cost
        from (select distinct cost
                from foo_v
               where foo_id < p_foo_id);
    when 'bar_v' then
      select listagg(cost, ';' ) within group (order by cost)
        into v_cost
        from (select distinct cost
                from bar_v
               where bar_id < p_bar_id);
  end case;

  return v_cost;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Usage example**

```
select cost_mk(p_view => 'foo_v', p_foo_id => 5) from dual;
select cost_mk(p_view => 'bar_v', p_bar_id => 5) from dual;
```

Answer (score -3):

You would want to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as was hinted by the comments to your question, define a new variable `sqlQuery VARCHAR2(200);` or similar and rework your sql similar to the following:

```
sqlQuery := 'Select Listagg(Costs, '';'' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Costs) ';
sqlQuery := sqlQuery || 'from (select distinct (Costs) from :1 where :2)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery INTO v_Costs USING VIEWNAME, WHERE_CLAUSE;
```

Comment: You can't use bind variables for the view name or for a dynamic `where` clause.  You can only use bind variables for, well, variable values like `where costs > :1`.